# ZeroClipboard - Add to values before copying

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I'm using the JS version of ZeroClipboard.

When the user clicks the copy button I want to capture the data from **data-clipboard-text**  add some extra data to this and then copy this to the clipboard.

This the code I'm currently using,  How do I add to the text before it is copied to the clipboard ?

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard( $("input[type='button']"), {
  moviePath: "clip/ZeroClipboard.swf"
});
clip.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
    alert ('Copied');
});
```

I've tried using this before `clip.on` but it failed :

```
clip.on('dataRequested', function (client, args) {
        clip.setText(args + "NEW VALUE");
    } );
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setting the clipboard text](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#text-to-copy) can be done using the 'copy' event handler [v2.x]  :

```
clip.on( "copy", function (event) {
    var clipboard = event.clipboardData;
    clipboard.setData( "text/plain", event.target.innerHTML + " <-- added this text!" );
    /*
     * for data-attribute use event.target.getAttribute("data-clipboard-text")
     */
});
```

- http://jsbin.com/zumaluzoxo/edit?html,css,js
- http://output.jsbin.com/zumaluzoxo/

---

[For previous version [1.x]](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/1.x-master/docs/instructions.md#text-to-copy) using the 'dataRequested' event handler:

```
client.on( 'dataRequested', function (client, args) {
  client.setText( this.getAttribute("data-clipboard-text") + "<- Copied me!" );
  /*
   * for text inside component use this.innerHTML
   */
});
```

Comment: Thanks - When I use `clip.on( 'dataRequested', function (client, args) {
  client.setText( args.text + "<- Copied me!" );
});` all that is copied is `undefined<- Copied me!`

Why am I not seeing the text ?

Comment: the args object doesn't have a text property. can you debug it or check your console by adding the line console.log(args) and see what it outputs. Maybe try to get the text by using .value or .textContent or .innerText

Comment: `console.log (args)` shows `Object {ctrlKey: false, shiftKey: false, altKey: false, flashVersion: "WIN 21,0,0,242"}`  However if I console log args.text it in the `clip.on complete function` then it does return the values

Comment: can you try this.innerHTML and this.getAttribute("data-clipboard-text") instead (sry, as I cant get it to run on JSBIN)

Comment: `this.innerHTML` returns nothing. But the other one does return my text to the console.

Comment: awesome. this.innerHTML is the text inside your element (which is empty) and this.getAttribute("data-clipboard-text")  is what you're looking for. updated code